# In a list of list of list, how to compare list of list with the same alphabet and append the values into a new list?

Tags: python, list

I got two list of list of list:

```
A=[[[0, 'a'], [2, 'g'], [9, 'Q']], [[2, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'g'], [15, 'w'], [2, 'Q']], [[15, 'g'], [0, 'w'], [7, 'Q']], [[9, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [2, 'g'], [7, 'w'], [0, 'Q']]]
B[[[0, 'a'], [0, 'Q'], [12, 'front'], [0, 'Z']], [[1, 'a'], [2, 'c'], [0, 'w'], [0, 'Q'], [2, 'front'], [0, 'Z']], [[0, 'Q'], [3, 'front'], [5, 'Z']], [[12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [2, 'w'], [3, 'Q'], [0, 'front'], [2, 'Z']], [[0, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'w'], [5, 'Q'], [2, 'front'], [0, 'Z']]]
```

For every list of list in it,I want to compare the alphabets.If the alphabets are in common append the list with the highest value number into the new list.If the alphabets are not in common,just append.

Output should be like:

```
 C=[[[0, 'a'],[2,'g'], [9, 'Q'], [12, 'front'], [0, 'Z']], [[1, 'a'],[[0,'g'], [2, 'c'], [0, 'w'], [0, 'Q'], [2, 'front'], [0, 'Z']],....
```

Comment: what have you tried and does the output items need to be in exact order shown ?

Comment: No the output does not need to be in the order shown.

Comment: plz explain a little bit more and indent your list properly it's bit messy to scroll horizontally and understand your posted list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the order of the output nested list elements and assuming length of input lists are equal:

```
A=[[[0, 'a'], [2, 'g'], [9, 'Q']], [[0, 'c'], [0, 'g'], [0, 'Q']], [[2, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'g'], [15, 'w'], [2, 'Q']], [[15, 'g'], [0, 'w'], [7, 'Q']], [[9, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [2, 'g'], [7, 'w'], [0, 'Q']]]
B=[[[0, 'a'], [0, 'Q'], [12, 'front'], [0, 'Z']], [[1, 'a'], [2, 'c'], [0, 'w'], [0, 'Q'], [2, 'front'], [0, 'Z']], [[0, 'Q'], [3, 'front'], [5, 'Z']], [[12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [2, 'w'], [3, 'Q'], [0, 'front'], [2, 'Z']], [[0, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'w'], [5, 'Q'], [2, 'front'], [0, 'Z']]]   

C=[]
for index in range(len(A)):
    list_a = A[index]
    list_b = B[index]
    if len(list_a) > len(list_b):
        loop_list=list_a
        comp_list=list_b
    else:
        loop_list=list_b
        comp_list=list_a        
    temp=[]
    found_list=[]
    for each_sub_list in loop_list:
            number = each_sub_list[0]
            alphabet = each_sub_list[1]
            found=0
            for index_b,each_sub_list_b in enumerate(comp_list):
                if alphabet == each_sub_list_b[1]:
                    found=index_b
                    found_list.append(comp_list[index_b])
                    break
            if found:
                if number > comp_list[found][0]:
                    temp.append(each_sub_list)
                else:
                    temp.append(comp_list[found])
            else:
                temp.append(each_sub_list)
    never_found_list = [item for item in comp_list if item not in found_list]
    temp.extend(never_found_list)
    C.append(temp)
print(C)
```

Comment: What if the length of input is not equal and I deleted the list of list with all o's like the lists I edited above?It doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of missing details needed to solve this correctly.

For example,

- In which order do you append items when a letter is higher in list 2?
- Does that matter?
- Are you just trying to solve this one case, or do you need a solution
  that works for any 3d lists?
- "If the alphabets are not in common,just append"...HOW?

Anyways, hope this points you in the right direction.  Definitely not optimized and I'm sure there is a much simpler and elegant recursive way of approaching this problem.  But the idea is breaking it down so you are comparing the right elements, and then doing any necessary list appends.

```
a = [[[0, 'a'], [2, 'g'], [9, 'Q']], [[0, 'c'], [0, 'g'], [0, 'Q']], [[2, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'g'], [15, 'w'], [2, 'Q']], [[15, 'g'], [0, 'w'], [7, 'Q']], [[9, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [2, 'g'], [7, 'w'], [0, 'Q']]]

b = [[[0, 'a'], [0, 'Q'], [12, 'front'], [0, 'Z']], [[1, 'a'], [2, 'c'], [0, 'w'], [0, 'Q'], [2, 'front'], [0, 'Z']], [[0, 'Q'], [3, 'front'], [5, 'Z']], [[12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [2, 'w'], [3, 'Q'], [0, 'front'], [2, 'Z']], [[0, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'w'], [5, 'Q'], [2, 'front'], [0, 'Z']]]

group_a = {}
group_b = {}

count = 0
for x in a:
  group_a[count] = []
  for y in x:
    group_a[count].append(y)
  count+=1

count = 0
for x in b:
  group_b[count] = []
  for y in x:
    group_b[count].append(y)
  count+=1


new_list = []

for x in range(len(group_b)):
  first = group_a[x]
  second = group_b[x]
  for y in first:
    for z in second:
      if y[1] == z[1]:
        if y[0] > z[0]:
          break
        else:
          y[0] = z[0]

  for y in second:
    add = True
    for z in first:
      if y[1] == z[1]:
        add = False
    if add:
      first.append(y)

  new_list.append(first)

print(new_list)
```

Hopefully this helps you find that beautiful recursive solution that will work on all 3d lists, not just the two you provided above!

....and of course DRY (unlike what I did) in the better solution you come up with.

Comment: I removed one of the list of list and the code doesn't work anymore?

Comment: It returns keyError 4?

Answer (score 0):

use [itertools.izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) for handling different input list length, use [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) if you are using python 3.

`tmp` holding the zip item from both list

Then, sorted the list based on index 1 follow by index 0 key in reverse order, item with alphabat will be group together in order of value from high to low.

Then, we only take the 1st highest value item and ignore lower value item

```
A=[[[0, 'a'], [2, 'g'], [9, 'Q']], [[2, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'g'], [15, 'w'], [2, 'Q']], [[15, 'g'], [0, 'w'], [7, 'Q']], [[9, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [2, 'g'], [7, 'w'], [0, 'Q']]]
B=[[[0, 'a'], [0, 'Q'], [12, 'front'], [0, 'Z']], [[1, 'a'], [2, 'c'], [0, 'w'], [0, 'Q'], [2, 'front'], [0, 'Z']], [[0, 'Q'], [3, 'front'], [5, 'Z']], [[12, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [2, 'w'], [3, 'Q'], [0, 'front'], [2, 'Z']], [[0, 'a'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'w'], [5, 'Q'], [2, 'front'], [0, 'Z']]]

C = []
for a,b in itertools.izip_longest(A,B):
  tmp = []
  mem = set()
  if a:
    tmp.extend(a)  
  if b:
    tmp.extend(b)
  sorted_list = sorted(tmp, key=lambda x:(x[1],x[0]), reverse=True)
  inner_out = []
  for i in sorted_list:
    if i[1] not in mem:
      inner_out.append(i)
    mem.add(i[1])
  C.append(inner_out)

# C = [[[2, 'g'], [12, 'front'], [0, 'a'], [0, 'Z'], [9, 'Q']], [[15, 'w'], [0, 'g'], [2, 'front'], [2, 'c'], [2, 'a'], [0, 'Z'], [2, 'Q']], [[0, 'w'], [15, 'g'], [3, 'front'], [5, 'Z'], [7, 'Q']], [[7, 'w'], [2, 'g'], [0, 'front'], [0, 'c'], [12, 'a'], [2, 'Z'], [3, 'Q']], [[0, 'w'], [2, 'front'], [0, 'c'], [0, 'a'], [0, 'Z'], [5, 'Q']]]
```